# create_graph Function does not works

Tags: database, postgresql, graph-databases, apache-age

I have done:

```
test=# SET search_path = ag_catalog, "$user", public;
```

But still I can not use `create_graph` function directly.

```
test=# create_graph('university');
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "create_graph"
LINE 1: create_graph('university');
```

**Why I need to do this using `ag_catalog`:**

```
test=# SELECT * FROM ag_catalog.create_graph('university');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You encountered a syntax error because you failed to use the `SELECT` statement, try modifying your query;

```
SELECT create_graph('university');
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM create_graph('university');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first query is incorrect because you are not using correct syntax.

This will work

```
new=# SELECT create_graph('university');
NOTICE:  graph "university" has been created
 create_graph 
--------------
 
(1 row)
```

but this will not

```
new=# create_graph('university');
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "create_graph"
LINE 1: create_graph('university');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't to use the `ag_catalog` for every apacheAGE function that you use. You can just use :

`SELECT * FROM create_graph('graph');`

The reason you need `SELECT *` is to signify to the backend to give results to you, I believe all apacheAGE functions need that.

Answer (score 0):

In the first query there is a syntax error it should be like that :

```
SELECT * FROM ag_catalog.create_graph('graph_name');
```

If you don't want to write `ag_catalog` every time you execute a query than you should set `search_path` as follow:

```
SET search_path to ag_catalog;
```

This is because `create_graph` is present in `ag_catalog` namespace So, you need either to set namespace to `ag_catalog` using `search_path` or by adding `ag_catalog.` as a prefix of any function call in `age`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `ag_catalog` to use the `create_graph()` function if you already run `SET search_path = ag_catalog, "$user", public;`, you can simply run the following command without `ag_catalog` and it should work: `SELECT * FROM create_graph('university');`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add the ag_catalog every time you make a query after setting the search_path.
This is the correct syntax for creating a graph called university `SELECT * FROM create_graph('university');`